# Bitcoin Core lost coins

Tags: bitcoin-core, lost-bitcoins, lost-wallet

i have lost a bit of coins using Bitcoin Core wallet.
I have send my coins from Bitcoin Core wallet to my address on Bitstamp(copy/paste,no mistake here) and on my Bitcoin Core wallet has said "sent" as allways...than my computer crashed and there was no way of fixing it other than format an re-install Windows. I know it was stupid not to have a backup of wallet, but it is too late for that. I tryed to find the transaction using the addres i have send to, but there is no transaction found.
I have no other info about my wallet, except a couple of addresses that i have generated on my Bitcoin Core wallet, when i was sending coins to my Bitcoin Core wallet.
Is there ANY way i can get my coins back?
And if not where are thay?
Will pay a finders fee :)

Comment: There's no way we can tell without the addresses involved or, at the very least, the timeline. Also, your description is vague everything. For example, you say "I tryed to find the transaction using the addres i have send to, but there is no transaction found" which doesn't tell us much because we have no idea what you tried.

Comment: Hi,thank you for responding...the addresi have send to is:3Bhe7JyMo5QyhHXMFveCNu9zJgVQbWkd5L i think it was on the 7.4..  i contacted bitstamp(where my reciving  wallet is),but thay said-  there have been no BTC sent to any of your BTC deposit addresses lately. In addition, there are no recent transactions broadcast on Blockchain. We would also kindly suggest you contact your wallet provider, as they should be able to assist you better.

Comment: Sorry it was on 6.4.

Comment: How long ago did you first attempt to send these coins? I do see transactions from January.

Comment: Hi, no i have send just once on 6.april 2017, and none of the block explorers can find it. I think my only chance i still have that i find the wallet data on my hard drive using using one of them recovery softwares. Do you know anything about that... what file am i looking for, and what to do with it,if i do find it? Thank you

Comment: You're looking for `wallet.dat`.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there ANY way i can get my coins back?**

No because you

- don't have a backup
- don't know the private key
- don't have any recovery phrase (if applicable)
- overwrote the disk
  (though there was still a tiny chance of recovering a wallet.dat)

> **And if not where are thay?**

They are in the blockchain but can never be used.